# SharePoint Site and Graph API (Beta) - can't find any pages under site and can't create page (access denied)

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently working with the SharePoint Graph API (beta) through Postman.
I have it all working and my Azure Active Directory application has the correct scopes for SharePoint.

What I am wondering is this:

I have this site (**subsite**, sorry my SharePoint terminology might not be the best):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/{{api-version}}/sites/COMPANY_NAME.sharepoint.com,070d3261-xxxx-4c69-b186-a83e7ee0b6bb,09bc2cd0-aada-45fb-xxxx-bcdce9d5711e:/kb:/
```

which returns the site I am looking for (**Note**: I truncated the json):

```
{
   "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#sites/$entity",
   "createdDateTime": "2020-05-18T06:02:28Z",
   "description": "",
   "id": "COMPANY_NAME.sharepoint.com,070d3261-xxxx-4c69-b186-a83e7ee0b6bb,e7808145-aab1-xxxx-bccc-df798f6a36eb",
   "lastModifiedDateTime": "2020-09-23T21:37:37Z",
   "name": "kb",
   "displayName": "Knowledge Base - I removed the rest of the json"
}
```

But when I add /pages to the end:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/{{api-version}}/sites/COMPANY_NAME.sharepoint.com,070d3261-xxxx-4c69-b186-a83e7ee0b6bb,09bc2cd0-aada-45fb-xxxx-bcdce9d5711e:/kb:/pages/
```

I get this:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.sitePage)",
    "value": []
}
```

Now, I just went and created a new page in that site, even though there were already pages there, so I know they exist.

Another thing to note is that when I try to create a new page via the API:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/{{api-version}}/sites/{{site-id}}/pages
```

I get this:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "accessDenied",
        "message": "Access denied",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-09-27T22:56:06",
            "request-id": "1306506d-caea-4748-99a9-7eee20bb6404",
            "client-request-id": "1306506d-caea-4748-99a9-7eee20bb6404"
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why the collection / array in my response does not contain any pages and also, why I cannot create a new page when my AAD App have the required scopes and these scopes have my admins' consent

cheers

Update. Adding some screen shots:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please tell us if you are the owner of the site or member of the site or not. I have tried creating a aspx page in my site pages and I was able to get pages data as owner and as member but not without the account which is in our tenant but not connected with the site.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity I neglected to mention I am not using Graph API as myself. All calls are done through an Azure Active Directory Application with SharePoint API permissions Sites.Read.All and Sites.ReadWrite.All

Comment: Could you please try adding Global Admin Role to that Application permission and see if it can help?

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity We did this this morning and it did not change anything.
I also get access denied when trying to create a new page. Will update my post to include create page info

Comment: Please add the permission 'Sites.ReadWrite.All' which is missing in your token. And now check if you are able to create and get the data.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity it's funny that you say that as I was just inspecting my JWT token and yes, Sites.ReadWrite.All is missing. The thing is, my Azure AAD App registration has always had Sharepoint - Sites.ReadWrite.All. See newly added pics up in the question. I can't work out why my JWT token is missing this even though the scope has been added. My JWT token only shows the Microsoft Graph scopes but none of the SharePoint scopes.

Comment: you are actually adding it for Sharepoint App permissions, please add the Sites.ReadWrite.All for the Microsoft Graph Permissions. As you can see above the green pointer there are 3 permissions(Directory.Read.All, User.Read.All and User.Read), add "Sites.ReadWrite.All" there.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity oh great. That made things better. You are a legend. I did not realise that Sites.ReadWrite.All needed to be in the graph section AND the SharePoint section. In my mind doesn't it make sense that SharePoint stuff should be in the SharePoint section of the API permissions page?

Comment: There is no need of permissions in the sharepoint section, Are you able to get the pages? :)-

Comment: @Shiva. Yes I can do everything now. Got my python code creating pages. Thanks so much. Still confused why I don’t need to put the SharePoint thing in the SharePoint section. Seems odd !!

Comment: Glad to here that :)-

Comment: Moving this to Answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said you are using a daemon Application you need to specify right permissions here.
The screen shot shows that you are actually adding it for Sharepoint App permissions, please add the Sites.ReadWrite.All for the Microsoft Graph Permissions. As you can see above the green pointer there are 3 permissions(Directory.Read.All, User.Read.All and User.Read), add "Sites.ReadWrite.All" there to get the site pages and also it helps you in creating the pages.